# Connect two different domain servers to transfer data

Tags: domain-controller, upgrade

Planning an upgrade from 2003 (Small Business Server) to 2012, question is how to transfer the data.

Can I connect these two servers together by connecting by IP number and using simple file sharing or will the issue of them being on two different domains prevent this?  What about if I use the same domain name for both servers, how will having two domain controllers on the same network temporarily work out.

I realize that we could demote the old server to be a simple server and not a domain controller, that could then be added to the new domain.  However I would prefer to leave the old server configured as is to act as a backup in case of any problems with the new server.

Edit:
Guess I wasn't clear here, when I say upgrade all I meant was that we are buying a new server and installing Server 2012 on it.  The old server is running 2003.  Question is if both servers are on the network at the same time will one be able to see the other?  Bear in mind that they are both going to be domain controllers.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get your terminology right. You cannot upgrade from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012. What you are doing is migrating from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012.
2. Don't overcomplicate things. Either use an external USB drive to transfer the data or transfer it over the network (via UNC path) and provide the appropriate credentials when prompted. There's nothing about this that needs to be complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet with Small Business Server is to do a swing migration.  You can order a kit from www.sbsmigration.com and it is well worth the money as it walks you straight through it.  If you already knew how to do it, you wouldn't need the kit, obviously, but it definitely is worth the costs.

Unless you really meant 2012 server and not SBS 2011, in which case you have to take into account if the SBS server is running Exchange, SQL, Sharepoint, etc. before going down the path of migrating over to an actual 2012 server (and the new licensing for both the server and the CALs that would be required now).

EDIT based on your EDIT: yes you can attach/bring in a 2012 server and then migrate over time to it if you want.  See here on Technet for a walkthrough: http://blogs.technet.com/b/infratalks/archive/2012/09/07/transition-from-small-business-server-to-standard-windows-server.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you simply need to transfer some files. If you have a correct username and password in the domain you should be able to connect and upload your files. Solution 2, connect with a remote desktop and upload your files through it (slower). Or, if you got any troubles or want some piece of mind, why can't you install some ftp server like filezilla... you can set it up in 5 minutes and remove it in even less time when you're done.

Comment: There will be two domain controllers one the old 2003 server and also the new 2012 server.  Question is can the new 2012 server see the old server or will it have problems because of there being two domain controllers.  Can I name the new domain the same as the old one or is there any reason for using a different domain name